# CTE within a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to write a CTE within a CTE?

I want it to follow this logic, but the interpreter doesn't like this code.

```
with outertest as(

    with test as (
        select 
            SRnum, 
            gamenumber, 
            StartOfDistribution, 
            ApplicationNumber   
        from #main
        where startofdistribution = '2011-06-14 00:00:00.000'
        and SRnum = '313'
        --order by SRnum, gamenumber, StartOfDistribution, ApplicationNumber
    )
    select
        ApplicationNumber
        ,count(*) as RetailerAppearance
    from test
    group by ApplicationNumber
    having count(*) = 4

) select count(*) from outertest
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can't nest CTEs like that in SQL Server but you can use multiple CTEs the following way:

```
;with test as 
(
    select 
        SRnum, 
        gamenumber, 
        StartOfDistribution, 
        ApplicationNumber   
    from #main
    where startofdistribution = '2011-06-14 00:00:00.000'
    and SRnum = '313'
    --order by SRnum, gamenumber, StartOfDistribution, ApplicationNumber
),
 outertest as
 (
    select
        ApplicationNumber
        ,count(*) as RetailerAppearance
    from test
    group by ApplicationNumber
    having count(*) = 4
) 
select count(*) 
from outertest
```

Comment: Seems like you can only run either one of the two cte queries. Any way of running both?

Comment: @Naufal I'm not sure I understand your question. This chains the CTEs together so they run at the same time.

Comment: What I mean is running the two nested CTEs together at the same time e.g. with cte1 as (query1), cte2 as (query2) select * from cte1, select * from cte2. But I know that's not the case, CTEs are not designed to perform the aforementioned operation. I managed to find another way around this and it was Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible, with a bit of modification to your code.
Just add a select before the outer CTE

NOTE: Works well in Teradata

```
with outertest as(
   SELECT * FROM (
       with test as (
           select 
               SRnum, 
               gamenumber, 
               StartOfDistribution, 
               ApplicationNumber   
           from #main
           where startofdistribution = '2011-06-14 00:00:00.000'
           and SRnum = '313'
           --order by SRnum, gamenumber, StartOfDistribution, ApplicationNumber
       )
       select
           ApplicationNumber
           ,count(*) as RetailerAppearance
       from test
       group by ApplicationNumber
       having count(*) = 4 ) OUTER_CTE
   
   ) select count(*) from outertest
```