# CTE inside CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please don't mark this question as duplicate of [CTE within a CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728474/cte-within-a-cte) .. I checked that question and answer ... but that answer does not satisfy my need.

I want to run Nested CTE query like this

```
Drop Table #Temp
Create Table #Temp(name1 text, name2 text)

Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')
Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')

;WITH CTE1 AS (
   With CTE2 as ( Select * from #Temp)
)

Select * from CTE1
```

or

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
   Select * From (With CTE2 as ( Select * from #Temp))
)

Select * from CTE1
```

In our structure... the inner CTE2 query have been provided by other system .. so I can't control 
inner part of the query... so.. here my duty is only select values from inner query and form new CTE in my system ...

And please imagine this

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
       "Query Provide by Other System"
    )
```

In some cases the "Query Provide by Other System" start with CTE..this may or may not be the CTE query... that is the exact problem for I can't use like below

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
   Select * From 
)
,With CTE2 as
 ( Select * from #Temp))
```

pls help anyone to prcoeed this, I guess my need is too dynamic

Comment: Why not just use `With CTE2 as ( Select * from #Temp), CTE1 AS (SELECT * FROM CTE2) SELECT * FROM CTE1;`, you don't need to nest them.

Comment: The linked answer seems to exactly answer your question. Maybe you don't fully understand what a CTE is? It is an inline view, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry, actually as I said, I don't have any control with inner query...and the inner query may or may not be a CTE query...this is just a query returns set of values(table values) and this query provide by other system.. so I don't know.. how is looks like..

Comment: How do you know the query will even parse? Or will reference valid tables? How do you intend to reference the output of the the query from the other system if you don't know what columns it contains, or if it is a CTE, or what data types there will be? Your problem appears to be much more deep rooted than just nesting CTEs!

Comment: Hi @GarethD , In my need, I don't care about what kind columns the query returns... here I will just consider it returns set of rows...and my duty is do paging in returned results, then take only required rows..

Comment: https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-recursive-cte/

Answer (score 8):

Just to have an idea:

```
;WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM ...
),
cte2 as
(
    SELECT * FROM ...
),
cte3 as
(
    SELECT * FROM ... INNER JOIN cte2 ON...
),
SELECT *
FROM
    cte1
    INNER JOIN cte3 ON   ...
```

Comment: Sorry, actually as I said, I don't have any control with inner query...and the inner query may or may not be a CTE query...this is a query just returns set of values(table values)...

Answer (score 6):

Separate your CTEs with `,`s rather than nesting them.

```
;
WITH
  CTE2 AS
(
  SELECT * FROM #Temp
)
,
  CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT * FROM CTE2
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  CTE1
```

**EDIT : Following your additional comments**

As I understand it, you are being provided with a system generated query that you then want to embed in another query.  Sometimes that system generated query uses a CTE, sometimes it doesn't; you don't know in advance the format of that query.

Unfortunately for you this means that you ***can not*** embed this within another CTE.

One option *could* be to use real views.

```
CREATE VIEW xxx AS
  <system generated code here>
;

SELECT
  *
FROM
  xxx
;
```

You do then, however, have to be very careful about concurrency; two concurrent users trying to create the same view with the same name.

The better solution would be to approach the vendor of the system with is creating the system generated query and ask them how they propose you use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ...so there is no temp/dynamic view? like temp table for single connection?

Comment: I can't create view like this

Answer (score 0):

```
;with BASE AS (
    SELECT * FROM table1
), BASE2 AS (
   SELECT * from table2
), BASE3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM table3
) SELECT * FROM BASE INNER JOIN BASE3 ...
```

I guess this is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your system generated query uses db qualified object names you can hack this by using `OPENQUERY`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *
    FROM    OPENQUERY([Your Server], 'Query Provide by Other System')
) 
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE;
```

You may need to configure your server for data access:

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'your server', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE;
```